# Java program to check spanish ID letter

Tags: java

the user has to type their ID, including the letter (example 19452100G) the program has to say if the letter is correct or not. If the letter is not correct, the program will write the correct one.

```
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter ID number: ");
     int numID = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.printf("letter corresponde %d is %c", numID, calculateLetter(numID));
     sc.close();
}

private static char calculateLetter(int id){
     String caracteres="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
     int resto = id%23;
     return caracteres.charAt(resto);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static char calcularLetraArray(int dni){
     char caracteres[] = {'T','R','W','A','G','M','Y','F','P','D','X','B','N','J','Z','S','Q','V','H','L','C','K','E'};
     int resto = id%23;
     return caracteres[resto];
}
}
```

Comment: "the user has to type their ID, including the letter" you are reading an `int`, which can't hold a letter.

Answer (score 0):

1.You are storing a String variable inside a Integer Variable.

2.Also there is no need of two methods for checking letter and correcting the letter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter ID number: ");
    String numID = sc.nextLine();
    char letter_corresponde = calculateLetter(numID);
    System.out.printf("letter corresponde %s is %c \n", numID, letter_corresponde);
    if (numID.charAt(numID.length()-1) == letter_corresponde)
        System.out.println("letter_corresponde matches no need to correct it");
    else {
        System.out.println("Correcting the letter_corresponde");
        numID = numID.substring(0,numID.length()-1) + letter_corresponde;
        System.out.println(numID);
    }
        
}
public static char calculateLetter(String numID){
    String caracteres="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    int id = Integer.parseInt(numID.substring(0,numID.length()-2));
    int resto = id%23;
    return caracteres.charAt(resto);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's why you need to add what is the problem statement for the above-given code , please add some input/outputs so that we can understand what you want to achieve

Comment: instead of 
`numID.substring(0,numID.length()-2)`
the correct

`numID.substring(0,numID.length()-1)`

Comment: @Emmy So now your problem is solved! Great thanks for correction!